# TechTool Pro surface scan No bad blocks, SMART failed

Tags: hard-drive, storage

I have a HDD which stores pdfs. So far I haven't had problems accessing the files.
I ran a complete surface scan using TechTool Pro which said no bad blocks.
Right before I ran the surface scan the HDD passed the SMART check.
After I ran the surface scan the HDD failed the SMART check.

Can I trust TechTool Pro to scan my other HDDs?

Comment: What type of drive are we talking about - SSD or regular hard disk drive? - Which part of the SMART check failed? ... When you say if you can trust it, do you mean that you're disappointed that it said no bad blocks? - or are you concerned that it broke your drive resulting in the failed SMART check?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience long scans to test hard drives (solid state drives have different failures and should never be scanned this way!) heat up the drives and stress them further.  If the drive was listed as healthy the first time but failed afterwards, it probably was already in decline and just could not take the extra stress.

That said, you should use a second utility to check the S.M.A.R.T. statistics.  I check the SMART details *before* running any scans.  My favorite utility on Macs is DriveDX, and it is well worth the money.  There is no better one I have found.  On Windows there are several tools I like, but the only other options on Mac are:

- Smartmontools (a command line utility that you can install via Brew).
- Drive Scope by Micromat (probably the same tool as in Techtool Pro)
- Disk Warrior: did not update for APFS and might not even work in Sonoma
- Smart Reporter or Smart Utility on the App Store: although I was not impressed by either.

SMART stats are not easy to read, so I highly advise starting with a tutorial or just installing DriveDX.